# When is it "safe" to modify a given html element/node while parsing the document?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

When parsing and modifying an HTML page, I only want to change the text content and don't want to touch `script` and `style` tags (there's sure to be a heap more I don't want to mess with either).

Short of explicitly checking `nodeName != "SCRIPT"`, is there a clean way to parse and modify only the text on an html page?

Comment: You really need to back up and describe the REAL problem you're trying to solve for us to know how best to advise you.  Right now, you're obviously trying to do something unusual and that's causing you some problems, but we can only give you good advice if you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm playing with parsing web pages from a chrome extension. Just replacing text for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change content except for `script` and `style` tags, it sounds very reasonable to check for them.

```
node.nodeName != 'SCRIPT' && node.nodeName != 'STYLE'
```

Comment: As I'm not that experienced with web dev, I'm assuming there's other tags too, that I don't know about and am wondering if I can refer to them as a collective. For example a `div`/`span`/`p` behaves differently to `script`/`style`/`object` etc.

Comment: @jozxyqk: No, you'll just have to build yourself either a whitelist or a blacklist. The element types are [documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1).

Comment: @ Paul: +1 Beware that if the page is XHTML, those names won't be in caps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the OP explicitly specified HTML, but good point.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Well, XHTML is the XML serialization of HTML, so... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to walk the DOM and examine/modify only displayed text, then you need to special case a bunch of tag types and avoid stepping into them or modifying them.  In that list are: `<script>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>` and `<style>`.

In case you're interested, here's a tree walking function I have used that skips those tags and has been through some performance optimization to work quicker than recursive implementations.  This probably isn't the exact function you want, but you can get the general idea for skipping tags.  This could be adapted with a small change to call the callback only on text nodes:

```
var treeWalkFast = (function() {
    // create closure for constants
    var skipTags = {"SCRIPT": true, "IFRAME": true, "OBJECT": true, "EMBED": true, "STYLE": true};
    return function(parent, fn, allNodes) {
        var node = parent.firstChild, nextNode;
        while (node && node != parent) {
            if (allNodes || node.nodeType === 1) {
                if (fn(node) === false) {
                    return(false);
                }
            }
            // if it's an element &&
            //    has children &&
            //    has a tagname && is not in the skipTags list
            //  then, we can enumerate children
            if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.firstChild && !(node.tagName && skipTags[node.tagName])) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            } else  if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // no child and no nextsibling
                // find parent that has a nextSibling
                while ((node = node.parentNode) != parent) {
                    if (node.nextSibling) {
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Just what I'm after, thanks! I'm currently using a `MutationObserver` which does most of that work for me. It doesn't seem to be terribly slow, but then maybe I just have low expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for `nodeName != "SCRIPT"`, you should query only the elements you need and modify them using `document.getElementsByName`, `document.getElementsByTagName`,...
If you use a library like jQuery, this should be a simple task to query only the elements you need to modify.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm parsing arbitrary web pages so this isn't an option.

Comment: @jozxyqk: this should not be a problem. You could use these method on an element instead of document. Try using jQuery, you could query only the elements you need

Comment: I need *all* the elements, except the ones that could damage the web page's functionality. Of course any modification could, but it's less likely if I don't mess with script tags.